# Excel VBA Pivot Table Wizard, set table destination and remove grand totals

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

The below works well, however I want the destination sheet to be a specific existing sheet called `"PIVOT"`. Also I would like to remove grand totals for both `rows` and `columns`. Any ideas?

```
Sub CreatePivot()
' Creates a PivotTable report from the table on Sheet1
' by using the PivotTableWizard method with the PivotFields
' method to specify the fields in the PivotTable.
Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField

' Select the sheet and first cell of the table that contains the data.
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Select
Range("A1").Select

' Create the PivotTable object based on the Employee data on Sheet1.
Set objTable = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").PivotTableWizard

' Specify row and column fields.
Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("CCY")
objField.Orientation = xlRowField

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("ACC")
objField.Orientation = xlRowField

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("VD")
objField.Orientation = xlColumnField

' Specify a data field with its summary
' function and format.
Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("AMOUNT")
objField.Orientation = xlDataField
objField.Function = xlSum
objField.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destination sheet can be defined by the `TableDestination` parameter of `PivotTableWizard`, then you can remove the grand totals with: `ColumnGrand` and `RowGrand`. Here is the changed code:

```
Sub CreatePivot()
' Creates a PivotTable report from the table on Sheet1
' by using the PivotTableWizard method with the PivotFields
' method to specify the fields in the PivotTable.
Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField

' Select the sheet and first cell of the table that contains the data.
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Select
Range("A1").Select

' Create the PivotTable object based on the Employee data on PIVOT with the name 'PivotTableName'.
Set objTable = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:="PIVOT!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTableName")

'Remove grand totals
With Sheets("PIVOT").PivotTables("PivotTableName")
    .ColumnGrand = False
    .RowGrand = False
End With

' Specify row and column fields.
Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("CCY")
objField.Orientation = xlRowField

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("ACC")
objField.Orientation = xlRowField

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("VD")
objField.Orientation = xlColumnField

' Specify a data field with its summary
' function and format.
Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("AMOUNT")
objField.Orientation = xlDataField
objField.Function = xlSum
objField.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

End Sub
```