# How can I prevent Total and Grand Total rows from being generated for PivotTables (C# / Excel Interop)?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I've got a PivotTable that looks like so:

[image]

Notice, though, that it sports a "Total" row for each "real" row; also, a "Grand Total" row at the end. These are totally superfluous - this data needs no totalizing.

I thought maybe it was because I needed to change one of the args passed to the PivotTableWizard method from "true" to false, so I found [this documentation for it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839228.aspx) and thought the fix would be to change the vals of the fifth and sixth args from true to false like so:

```
 _xlBook.PivotTableWizard(
        Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase,
        pivotData,
        pivotDestination,
        pivotTableName,
        false, //true,
        false, //true,
        true,
        true,
        useDefault,
        useDefault,
        false,
        false,
        Excel.XlOrder.xlDownThenOver,
        0,
        useDefault,
        useDefault
);
```

...but it made no difference - I still get those rogue/spurious "Total" rows.

How can I prevent the Totals rows from being generated/displaying?

### UPDATE

[This MS page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.pivottablewizard.aspx) specifically shows that setting the "RowGrand" arg to true will show grand totals for rows, and the next arg, "ColumnGrand" is similarly engineered.

However, setting those vals to false like I do:

```
static readonly object useDefault = Type.Missing;
string pivotTableName = @"Pivot Test";
. . .
pivotData = _xlSheet.Range["A1:D25"];
pivotDestination = _xlSheet.Range["F7", useDefault];
_xlBook.PivotTableWizard(
        Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, // SourceType
        pivotData,                               // SourceData
        pivotDestination,                        // TableDestination
        pivotTableName,                          // TableName
        false, //true,                           // RowGrand
        false, //true,                           // ColumnGrand
        true,                                    // SaveData
        true,                                    // HasAutoFormat
        useDefault,                              // AutoPage
        useDefault,                              // Reserved
        false,                                   // BackgroundQuery
        false,                                   // OptimizeCache
        Excel.XlOrder.xlDownThenOver,            // PageFieldOrder
        0,                                       // PageFieldWrapCount
        useDefault,                              // ReadData
        useDefault                               // Connection
);
```

...makes no difference - the PivotTable still displays the unwanted totals - what the ISIS is going on here?

### UPDATE 2

I switched things up a bit by using the MS post [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd891207(v=office.12).aspx) as a basis, and came up with this:

```
private void GeneratePivotTableOnSheet2()
{
    // Select a range of data for the Pivot Table.
    pivotData = _xlSheet.get_Range("A1", "D25");

    // Select location of the Pivot Table.
    pivotDestination = _xlSheet.get_Range("A32", useDefault);

    // Add a Pivot Table to the Worksheet.
    _xlBook.PivotTableWizard(
        Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase,
        pivotData,
        pivotDestination,
        pivotTableName2,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        useDefault,
        useDefault,
        false,
        false,
        Excel.XlOrder.xlDownThenOver,
        0,
        useDefault,
        useDefault
        );

    // Set variables for used to manipulate the Pivot Table.
    pivotTable =
        (Excel.PivotTable)_xlSheet.PivotTables(pivotTableName2);
    titlePivotField = ((Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(1));
    authorPivotField = ((Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(2));
    //pubyearPivotField = ((Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(3));

    // Format the Pivot Table.
    pivotTable.Format(Excel.XlPivotFormatType.xlReport2);
    pivotTable.InGridDropZones = false;

    // Set Sales Region as a Row Field.
    titlePivotField.Orientation =
        Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
    authorPivotField.Orientation =
        Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
    //pubyearPivotField.Orientation =
    //    Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;

    _xlSheet.Columns.AutoFit();

    Directory.CreateDirectory(PivotTablePracticeConstsAndUtils.OUTPUT_DIRECTORY);
    String _uniqueFolder = PivotTablePracticeConstsAndUtils.OUTPUT_DIRECTORY;
    string filename = String.Format("{0}\\TwainBooks.xlsx", _uniqueFolder);
    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        File.Delete(filename);
    }

    _xlBook.SaveAs(filename, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    MessageBox.Show("File has been written");
}
```

With this, the results are somewhat promising, but still confounding; here's why:

If I declare two PivotFields (title and author), and THEN select a third (pub year) by selecting the checkbox on the generated spreadsheet, and THEN filter one of the values, the data is displayed in the PivotTable. Prior to that, ONLY the column titles display - I must both manually check "pub year" AND filter the data (not retain the "All" value the columns have selected by default) to see any data.

It should show all the data from the git-go, right (with all the "All"s selected)?

And then why would adding the "pub year" PivotField work (sort of) when done manually, but if I try to add it programmatically (the commented-out "pubyearPivotField" lines in the code above), it doesn't?!?

IOW and in summation: a lot of ongoing irritation going on, but no pearls as of yet.

### UPDATE 3

This is definitely goofier than Goofy and Barney Feif concatenated: With code that sets the Author PivotField as a Page type, and Title and YearPublished as Row Type, no data is displayed in the PivotTable when the sheet is opened.

HOWEVER, if I uncheck "Year Published" then re-check it (it was checked from the git-go) the data DOES display.

So this is obviously an Excel Interop bug; but is there a way to programmatically uncheck and then check that field?

### UPDATE 4

I tried this, too:

```
pubyearPivotField.EnableItemSelection = false;
pubyearPivotField.EnableItemSelection = true;
```

...but it didn't work.

### UPDATE 5

So I thought to record a macro of what's happening when I uncheck then re-check the "YEAR PUBLISHED" checkbox.

This is what was recorded:

```
Sub MacroUncheckCheckPTField()
'
' MacroUncheckCheckPTField Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTest3").PivotFields("Sum of YEAR PUBLISHED"). _
        Orientation = xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTest3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTest3").PivotFields("YEAR PUBLISHED"), "Sum of YEAR PUBLISHED", xlSum
End Sub
```

I don't know why the "Sum of " is part of that. I have set up no data fields; there IS a (bogus/unwanted) "Grand Total" row at the bottom of the PivotTable that sums up the year (which, of course, makes no sense/has no value).

But I don't know quite what to do with that macro - that is, how to convert it to C#.

When I tried it [here](http://converter.telerik.com/), I got, "*CONVERSION ERROR: Code could not be converted. Details:
-- line 1 col 1: EOF expected
Please check for any errors in the original code and try again."*

Yes, that is "VB" and not "VBA" but I thought it would be worth a try.

All I do in the sheet (manually) is first uncheck the "Year Published" checkbox, then re-check it; that's all it takes to get the data to display in the PivotTable. This is what it looks like:

[image]

I tried this (setting CurrentPage val only allowable on PageFields):

```
authorPivotField.CurrentPage = "(All)";
```

...but it made no difference.

### UPDATE 6

I tried this as a VBA-to-C# conversion of the macro:

```
_xlSheet.PivotTables("PivotTest3").PivotFields("Sum of YEAR PUBLISHED")._Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlHidden;
_xlSheet.PivotTables("PivotTest3").AddDataField(_xlSheet.PivotTables("PivotTest3")
    .PivotFields("YEAR PUBLISHED"), "Sum of YEAR PUBLISHED", Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum);
```

...but that blows up with: "*Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class*"

### UPDATE 7

So one of the problems, to my way of thinking, with the way the Excel Interop PivotTable code works is in the nomenclature for the various field types, which seems misleading or at best non-optimal to me.

The possible values for Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation are:

```
xlColumnField
xlDataField
xlHiddenField
xlPageField
xlRowField
```

What in tarheel nation do these do/how do they differ, each from its brethren? It's not always obvious from the Christian names they were given. I would propose these replacements as a way to better understand their raison d'etre:

```
xlColumnField = xlDisplayField (in my tests, I see no difference between this and xlRowField)
xlDataField = xlCalculatedField (it is a data field, but aren't they all?)
xlHiddenField = xlInitiallyHidden (it is available in the checkbox list, and checking it will visiblize it)
xlPageField = xlFilterField
xlRowField = xlDisplayField (in my tests, I see no difference between this and xlColumnField)
```

Comment: As stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32906044/4558029), you can remove these rows/columns with `Sheets(pivotDestination).PivotTables(pivotTableName)
    .ColumnGrand = False` and `Sheets(pivotDestination).PivotTables(pivotTableName)
    .RowGrand = False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by no means perfect (no data displays in the PivotTable until I first uncheck, then re-check, the "Year Published" checkbox from the "" dialog), but it does answer the question (eliminates the totals rows):

```
// Select a range of data for the Pivot Table.
pivotData = _xlSheet.get_Range("A1", "D25");

// Select location of the Pivot Table.
pivotDestination = _xlSheet.get_Range("A30", useDefault);

// Add a Pivot Table to the Worksheet.
_xlBook.PivotTableWizard(
    Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase,
    pivotData,
    pivotDestination,
    pivotTableName3,
    true,
    true,
    true,
    true,
    useDefault,
    useDefault,
    false,
    false,
    Excel.XlOrder.xlDownThenOver,
    0,
    useDefault,
    useDefault
    );

// Set variables for used to manipulate the Pivot Table.
pivotTable =
    (Excel.PivotTable)_xlSheet.PivotTables(pivotTableName3);
titlePivotField = ((Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(1));
authorPivotField = ((Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(2));
pubyearPivotField = ((Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(3));
statusPivotField = ((Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(4));

// Format the Pivot Table.
pivotTable.Format(Excel.XlPivotFormatType.xlReport2);
pivotTable.InGridDropZones = false;

// Set Page Field
authorPivotField.Orientation =
    Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField;

// Set Row Field[s]
titlePivotField.Orientation =
    Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
pubyearPivotField.Orientation =
    Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
statusPivotField.Orientation =
    Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlHidden;

authorPivotField.CurrentPage = "(All)";

_xlSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
```

Why exactly it does work (especially since the two "totals" arguments passed to PivotTableWizard are "true"), I don't grok, though...